# Use of Arrays.toString()

Tags: arrays

This has been revised to share my (almost completed) code.
I am trying to determine what I am missing with regard to this
line: System.out.println(" is " + Arrays.toString(AvgTemp.getTemp()));
Instead of printing all the elements in every row, just the element pertaining to the month.
Instead of receiving this:
The average temp for January is [45.0, 40.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

I should be seeing something like this:
The average temp for January is [45.0]

The question is what am I doing wrong to strip the needed element?

```
ArrayList<String> monthlist = new ArrayList<String>(12);
    AverageTemperature AvgTemp = new AverageTemperature();

    monthlist.add("January");
    monthlist.add("February");
    monthlist.add("March");
    monthlist.add("April");
    monthlist.add("May");
    monthlist.add("June");
    monthlist.add("July");
    monthlist.add("August");
    monthlist.add("September");
    monthlist.add("October");
    monthlist.add("November");
    monthlist.add("December");

    AvgTemp.Temp[0] = 45;
    AvgTemp.Temp[1] = 40;


    for (int index = 0; index < monthlist.size(); index++)
    {
        for (index = 0; index < monthlist.size(); index++)
        {
        System.out.print("The average temp for ");
        System.out.print(monthlist.get(index));
        System.out.println(" is " + Arrays.toString(AvgTemp.getTemp()));

        /**System.out.println("Temperature at index " + (index + 1) +
                " is: " + Arrays.toString(AvgTemp.getTemp()));
        */
         }
    }

}
```

}

```
public class AverageTemperature {
   private double AvgTemp;
   double[] Temp = new double[12];


   public AverageTemperature()
   {
      AvgTemp = 0.0;
   }

   public void setTemp(double[] t)
   {
      Temp = t;
   }

   public double [] getTemp()
   {
      return Temp;
   }
}
```

Comment: But which code ?

Comment: why is getTemp() returning an array?

Comment: If there is only 1 value, why use an array at all?

Comment: davidxxx -- The code I'm looking to modify is the one provided.
System.out.println(" is" + Arrays.toString(AvgTemp.getTemp()));

Comment: Totoro -- getTemp should be holding up to 12 different variables (one for each month)

Comment: Johnny Mopp -- for what I'm trying to do, I'd like to let java zero out whichever elements are not defined.  I have the first two defined, but want to put the value of each element to the month it corresponds to.

Comment: Courney: please [edit] your question and tell us all that is needed to know to understand your question, your code, and your problem. Don't bury key information in comments where most won't see it. Show the rest of the code pertaining to your problem. Also, if you only want one temp, why are you printing the whole array? Why not simply get the single item from the array that you're interested in?

Comment: Java is not an acronym.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the point of the `AverageTemperature` class is. It just seems to be a wrapper around an array. I'll assume this is a work-in-progress and ignore that.

`getTemp()` returns an array of all the months' temps. You need to index that array to print a single value:

```java
for (int index = 0; index < monthlist.size(); index++)
{
    // Why are there 2 for loops?
    //for (index = 0; index < monthlist.size(); index++)
    //{
    System.out.print("The average temp for ");
    System.out.print(monthlist.get(index));
    // Don't use toString, just index the array
    System.out.println(" is " + AvgTemp.getTemp()[index]);
    //}
}
```

Or:

```java
double[] avgTemps = AvgTemp.getTemp();
for (int index = 0; index < monthlist.size(); index++)
{
    System.out.print("The average temp for ");
    System.out.print(monthlist.get(index));
    System.out.println(" is " + avgTemps[index]);
}
```

To me it would be more logical to have `getTemp()` take an index and return a single value. Same with `setTemp()`:

```java
public class AverageTemperature {
   private double AvgTemp;
   // Make this private too
   private double[] Temp = new double[12];

   public AverageTemperature()
   {
      AvgTemp = 0.0;
   }

   public void setTemp(int index, double value)
   {
      // TODO: Add some index bounds checking
      Temp[index] = value;
   }

   public double getTemp(int index)
   {
      // TODO: Add some index bounds checking
      return Temp[index];
   }
}
```

Then, change your code to:

```java
AvgTemp.setTemp(0, 45);
AvgTemp.setTemp(1, 40);

for (int index = 0; index < monthlist.size(); index++)
{
    System.out.print("The average temp for ");
    System.out.print(monthlist.get(index));
    System.out.println(" is " + AvgTemp.getTemp(index));
}
```

<sub>You might also want to look at the [`Month Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) which you can use to make things more readable.</sub>